# Javascript: Unable to Firefox browser in Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, firefox, selenium

I am new to Selenium WebDriver. Learning it on my own using JavaScript. I am trying to launch Firefox browser.

Below is my machine stats:

1. Windows 7-64bit machine.
2. i5 Processor.
3. 8GB RAM.
4. Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

However, I am getting error. Can't attach error screenshot. Below is the description.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at BrowserInvocation.main(BrowserInvocation.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Please assist me.

Answer (score 1):

A `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown when the JRE can't find a class, in your case it probably can't find the Selenium. You need to add it to the classpath.

- Go to Project > Properties > Java build path
- In Libraries click Add External JARs
- Find selenium-java-2.48.0.jar file and add it (NOT
  selenium-java-2.48.0-srcs.jar).
- In the same folder you have Libs folder with more jar files, add them
  to.
- Click OK

You also need to make sure Selenium Standalone Server is also in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you do not have the Function class in your classpath.
"com.google.common.base.Function" seams to be in the Guava library (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava)

You can either add the corresponding jar thanks to your dependency manager (maven, gradle ...) or following guy's procedure.